# Python best practice: how to alias a module

Tags: python, python-import, pep

I am using a package `pkg` that has a submodule `module_with_long_name`. This module is imported by `pkg`, so I can use `module_with_long_name` without explicitly importing it:

```py
import pkg
pkg.do_stuff()
pkg.module_with_long_name.do_other_stuff()
```

But I want to alias this module since it has a long name, and I can't find any PEP convention saying which of the two following is best practice:

```py
import pkg
# First way
from pkg import module_with_long_name as module
# Second way
module = pkg.module_with_long_name
```

Do you know any reference on this issue?

Comment: The from ... import might be clearer when we are looking for what `module` is in the code, and it's at the top of the file with every other import

Comment: IMO the first way is much clearer, because it always puts together the imported module with its alias definition.

Comment: If the second way was best practice, the syntax that enables the first way probably wouldn't exist ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend always using the form:

```py
import package_name.subpackage_name.module_name as pkg_mod_abbrev
```

where `pkg_mod_abbrev` is an abbreviation that is suitable for the current module. This approach:

- aligns all `import` statements in the same way, independently of whether they rename the imported item (i.e., whether they contain the keyword `as`). This improves readability.
- keeps the import path contiguous. This is more readable. Writing `from package_name.subpackage_name import module_name as pkg_mod_abbrev` splits the module name from the other part of the import path. This requires skipping the `import` keyword that occurs between the first part of the import path, and the module name. Reading that would require more time.
- encourages either:

  - using the full import path inside the module (i.e., `package_name.subpackage_name.module_name`), or
  - creating an abbreviation that is suited to the current module (i.e., `pkg_mod_abbrev`)

  and thus avoiding using `module_name` (writing `import package_name.subpackage_name.module_name as module_name` is still possible, but writing an `as` renaming would likely by itself prompt choosing a suitable abbreviation; whereas `from` ... `import` would define `module_name` in absence of aliasing using `as`).

[Hiding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) the imported module `_pkg_mod_abbrev` is useful, more so for cases where the name of the module would coincide with a name that is convenient to be used for variables (also [this PEP 8 section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)).

For example, `bdd` abbreviates "Binary Decision Diagram". The package [`dd`](https://pypi.org/project/dd) has a module named `bdd`. It is convenient to name `bdd` Python variables that are instances of the class `dd.bdd.BDD`. Nonetheless, it is convenient to also name "bdd" the module `dd.bdd`. Hiding the imported module enables both, which also improving introspection:

```py
import dd.bdd as _bdd


def _main():
    bdd = _bdd.BDD()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

By [PEP 8, imported names are an implementation detail](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces). So even when unhidden, they are not part of the module's API.

Comment: After two years, I had lost hope to get a useful answer here. Thanks a lot for bringing such a detailed one!